# Where can I find this hadith on shaking hands?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

It is possible that this hadith is from a Shia Hadith Book, but I am not sure. I have not been able to find it yet.

> The Prophet (صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم) is reported to have said: "It is not permitted for women to contact with non-intimate except with covers of cloth."

If possible, please provide the authenticity as well.

Source: https://www.al-islam.org/some-questions-related-womens-rights-islam-sayyid-rida-husayni-nasab/what-commandment-shaking-hands

Comment: There is a (weak) hadith narrated by at-Tabaraani (Al-Awsat 2855) that the prophet would shake hands with women under covers of cloth, but the *matn* (ان النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم كان يصافح النساء تحت الثوب) is very different from the one you're asking for here.

Comment: @goldPseudo Thank you very much for your answer! Please let me know if you find anything on this hadith as well. I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: The source is a shi'a site. But even if there might not be a sahih hadith with the same content in sunni compilations the same fiqh view exists.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I've never seen this hadith cited by Sunni scholars, such as Yusuf Qaradawi. So, is it fair to assume that it is daif?

Comment: @HaseebFaisal well to qualify its authenticity it needs a qualification in hadith sciences which al-Qaradawi certainly doesn't have. And I have not yet even searched for the hadith nor found any qualification. But I know of ahadith requiring women to wear gloves...

Comment: @Medi1Saif Are those hadith daif like the one goldPseudo mentioned?

Comment: @Medi1Saif I was wondering if you know of the authenticity of the ahadith that you know of, requiring women to wear gloves?